# Camera keeps rotating

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to make a first-person game in Unity but I keep having issues with my character controller. The player keeps rotating when it collides with objects that have physics (*Or rigidbody*)

It doesn't rotate when it collides with objects that don't have physics.

It's not my mouse because my MouseX and Y Values aren't changing.

Here is the code for the Player

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Netcode;

public class PlayerControllerRB : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10f;
    public float jumpHeight = 4.65f;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody rb;

    private PlayerInput playerInput;
    private PlayerInput.OnFootActions onFoot;

    [SerializeField] private Camera cam;

    public float xSensitivity = 8f;
    public float ySensitivity = 8f;

    private float xRotation;

    private float yMovement;
    private float hMovement;

    [SerializeField] private Transform Feet;
    [SerializeField] public LayerMask Ground;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        playerInput = new PlayerInput();
        onFoot = playerInput.onFoot;

        onFoot.Jump.performed += ctx => Jump();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    #region

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        playerInput.Enable();
        onFoot.Enable();
    }
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        playerInput.Disable();
        onFoot.Disable();
    }

    #endregion

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        ProcessMove(onFoot.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>());
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        ProcessLook(onFoot.Look.ReadValue<Vector2>());
    }

    void ProcessMove(Vector2 input)
    {
        Vector3 MoveDirection = Vector3.zero;

        hMovement = input.x;
        yMovement = input.y;

        MoveDirection = transform.forward * yMovement + transform.right * hMovement;

        //MoveDirection.y = rb.velocity.y;

        Debug.Log(MoveDirection * speed);
        rb.AddForce(MoveDirection * speed, ForceMode.Acceleration);
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        Ray ray = new Ray(Feet.position, Vector3.down);

        RaycastHit info;

        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out info, 0.3f, Ground))
        {
                    rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpHeight, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }

    }
    void ProcessLook(Vector2 input)
    {
        float MouseY = input.y;
        float MouseX = input.x;

        xRotation -= (MouseY * Time.deltaTime) * ySensitivity;

        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -80f, 80f);

        cam.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0, 0);

        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * (MouseX * Time.deltaTime) * xSensitivity);
    }
}
```

I tried freezing the y rotation but then I get a jittry camera.

Can anyone help me? *It would also be nice if you had any recommendations to improve the controller.*

Please comment if you need any more information. *Sorry if the post is junk, I'm new to Stackoverflow*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you said It doesn't rotate when it collides with objects that don't have physics. In order to use the colliders one of them has to have a rigibody component. So if that's the case maybe is the script that is inside the `oncollisionenter` causing the problems. But I don't see any `oncollisionenter` script here

Comment: No, I am not using a ```oncollisionenter``` script. I did try freezing the y rotation that works but then it gives me a jittery camera.